# A error when using react-native with expo + redux + ex-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, ex-navigation

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { NavigationProvider, StackNavigation, NavigationContext } from '@expo/ex-navigation';
import Router from './routers';
import Store from './store/configureStore';

// Store & Router

const navigationContext = new NavigationContext({
  router: Router,
  store: Store,
})

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <NavigationProvider context={navigationContext}>
          <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
          <StackNavigation initialRoute={Router.getRoute('about')} />
        </NavigationProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

configureStore.js

```
import { createNavigationEnabledStore, NavigationReducer } from '@expo/ex-navigation';
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';

const createStoreWithNavigation = createNavigationEnabledStore({
  createStore,
  navigationStateKey: 'navigation',
});

const store = createStoreWithNavigation(
  combineReducers({
    navigation: NavigationReducer,
  })
);

export default store;
```

routers/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRouter } from '@expo/ex-navigation';

import About from './About';

export default createRouter(() => ({
  about: () => About,
}));
```

When run the code above on android avd, the avd will throw a error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigationState.navigators')

the detail error below:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigationState.navigators')

This error is located at:
    in Connect(FocusableComponent(ExNavigationStack)) (at ExNavigationConnect.js:42)
    in ExNavConnect (at ExNavigationComponents.js:114)
    in ExNavigatorComponent(ExNavigatorComponent) (at index.js:23)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at ExNavigationProvider.js:74)
    in ExNavigationProvider (at index.js:21)
    in Provider (at index.js:20)
    in App (at App.js:7)
    in App (created by AwakeInDevApp)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (created by AwakeInDevApp)
    in AwakeInDevApp (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:33)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:113)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
- node_modules/@expo/ex-navigation/src/ExNavigationComponents.js:33:20 in getStateForNavigatorId
```

[image]

Runtime Env:

- Android Emulator Google Pixel XL
- sdk version 27
- react-native: 0.50.3
- react: 16.0.0
- @expo/ex-navigation: 4.2.0
- expo: 23.0.6

how to fix the error above?

thanks